# Convert table to comma delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a single row in a table variable that looks like this:

```
CanEdit | CanView | CanAdd | CanDelete
```

All columns are bit fields.  I need to convert this table to a comma-delimited string like the following:

- If the user has true for each column...
  `E,V,A,D`
- If the user only has Edit and Add...
  `E,A`

How can I do this?

Comment: That's not something you should be doing within SQL. You should return all values and then in your front end decide how to display it. You shouldn't make front end design choices at the database level.

Comment: I disagree with the comments that this shouldn't be in the SQL layer.  SQL is a data processing tool, not some abstract engine for idealized software design.  Sometimes you might want to do this on the app side.  More often, you would want to do this in the database layer, specifically so different interfaces would all see the same thing.  In such a case, it would typically be in a view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I disagree with your disagreement with the original disagreement with the OPs original premise. I think.  *(There are indeed always exceptions, but this really is considered an anti-pattern in most circumstances by many people.)*

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much of a choice in this.  I'm creating a view that will be connected directly to Excel....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a fixed set, it can be done directly as follows.

```
SUBSTRING(
    CASE WHEN CanEdit   = 1 THEN ',E' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN CanView   = 1 THEN ',V' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN CanAdd    = 1 THEN ',A' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN CanDelete = 1 THEN ',D' ELSE '' END,
  2,
  7
)
```

That said, it is very rare that this is recommended.

If you are refactoring your data, this is reversing the atomicity of your data and is considered a fundamentally problematic anti-pattern in SQL.

If you are doing this for presentation in a client, doing this in SQL couples your data layer and presentation layer, another anti-pattern.

Comment: @ChrisShouts - I quote `All columns are bit fields`

Comment: This looks like the way I'll go.  Thanks Dems.